# advanced aggregation pandas python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by, pandas-groupby

If I have a simple table, such as:

```
index   location     col1   col2    col3    col4
    1          a     TRUE    yes       1       4
    2          a    FALSE   null       2       6
    3          b     TRUE   null       6       3
    4          b     TRUE     no       3       4
    5          b    FALSE    yes       4       6
    6          c     TRUE     no      57       8
    7          d    FALSE   null      74       9
```

If I wanted to aggregated the duplicate records in location, i.e the two a's or the three b's, I have been using a basic groupby functions. This works well for simple tables.

However, is it possible to expand this functionaility to allow rules per column when aggregating? As an example for col1, if TRUE was present, it would trump any FALSE value, or in col3, it would sum the values, whereas in col4 it add calculate the average? Is it possible to define these rules per column and then apply them when using groupby?

I have searched online, but not found anything that seems to cover this, however I may be barking up the wrong tree.

Thanks.

Comment: could you post desired / expected data set?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `groupby` and `agg`

```
funcs = dict(
    col1=dict(Trump=lambda x: x.any()),
    col3='sum',
    col4=dict(Avg='mean')
)

df.groupby('location').agg(funcs)
```

[image]

---

When using `agg` on a `groupby` object with multiple columns, you can pass a `dict` that defines which functions to apply to which column.

In this high level dictionary (`funcs`), the keys are the existing column names to apply the functions defined in the value.

For example:

```
agg({'col1': lambda x: x.any(), 'col2': 'sum'})
```

Says to use `any()` on `col1` and `sum` on `col2`.  If `col1` or `col2` did not exist in the dataframe, this would fail.

Further, we didn't have to live with the default column names that come from this aggregation.  I'll run the mini example above to illustrate.

```
df.groupby('location').agg({'col1': lambda x: x.any(), 'col3': 'sum'})
```

[image]

There isn't much description about what we've done.  We can describe the functions as we'd like if we pass a dictionary as the function instead, with the key being the description and the value being the function.  I'll use the same example but expanding it with a better description.

```
df.groupby('location').agg(
    {'col1': {'All I need is one True': lambda x: x.any()},
     'col3': {'SUMMATION': 'sum'}})
```

[image]

Armed with that information, hopefully my solution makes perfect sense.

Comment: @piRSquared what a fantastic answer! thank you for taking the time out! :D